# How to use the switch case in Scala to satisfy the condition?

Tags: scala

I have this code where I got stuck in the switch case syntax and future:

```
def getAll(implicit queryParams: QueryParams): Action[AnyContent] =
  securityService.authenticate() { implicit request =>
    withErrorRecovery { req =>
      toJson {
        repository.getAll(request.user.loginName).flatMap {
          xyz =>
            Future.sequence(xyz.map {
              abc =>
                if (abc.roleName != " ") { // getting error 
                  case Some(abc) => repotosecondquery.getrepo()
                }

              case None =>
                Future.failed(new
                    RuntimeException(NotFoundException()))
            })
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I'm not strong with Scala, I am studying it. But I cannot recognise in your code the pattern

    match{
       case: ...
       case: ...
    }

Comment: Not clear what your issue is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `xyz` to `case xyz`.

By the way it is pattern matching, not switch case.

Comment: Are you trying to say like this 
1.case xyz OR
2. case xyz =>
            Future.sequence(xyz.map {
              abc =>
                if (abc.roleName != " ") { // getting error 
                  case Some(xyz) => repotosecondquery.getrepo()